# Найти подлежащее и сказуемое

Tags: untagged

Предложение: "Печатать интереснее, чем читать". Где в первой части подлежащее и сказуемое? (Я думаю, что "печатать" - подлежащее, "интереснее" - сказуемое).

Comment: А разве наречие в сравнительной степени не всегда бывает обстоятельством? В отличие от сравнительная степени прилагательного, которое всегда сказуемое

Answer (score 1):

**Комментарий к ответу**

Рассуждения кажутся мне лукавой софистикой. Невольно задумаешься о том, что **формальный** грамматический анализ имеет существенные недостатки по сравнению со **структурно-семантическим** анализом, который представляется как более современный и эффективный способ.

Если особо не углубляться в детали, то что кажется очевидным? **Понятное пользователю предложение можно превратить с совершенно неопределенное и неясное.** Неужели по семантике трудно определить, где подлежащее и где сказуемое, смысл-то вполне прозрачный: печатание текста кажется более интересным занятием, чем его чтение.

Предмет (а не признак) – это "печатать", именно это подлежащее, а не наоборот. **Мы здесь определяем печатание, а не свои интересы** (тогда было бы так: самое интересное занятие для меня – это печатать).

*Печатать было интереснее, чем читать. Было интереснее печатать, чем читать*. Чем отличаются эти предложения? Д**а ничем не отличаются**, просто порядок слов изменен – обычное дело в русском языке, разве это неизвестно?  Но формалистика везде найдет способ, чтобы все усложнить и перевернуть.

Это мое личное мнение, вопрос дискуссионный.

Comment: Конечно, я привел эти цитаты намеренно, чтобы показать шероховатость синтаксиса и понятия сказуемого как предиката (Кстати, есть две теории сказуемого. В европейских языках оно пологичнее). Язык то логичен, синтаксис тоже, да вот только одно не отражает напрямую другое. Поэтому мне странно видеть в книгах утверждения типа: синтаксис это отражение и формализация внутренних законов реального языка. Это модель языка и, как всякая модель, всего лишь попытка что-то там отразить.

Comment: Конечно,  мы не поняли, что «намеренно», я считала, что это и ваше мнение тоже.  Что ж, мыслите вы разумно. Расскажу немного о двух теориях в  современной русской лингвистике. Цитата:  «В 60-е годы XX века особую исследовательскую активность приобрело семантическое направление, известное как семантическая семантика». Далее речь идет о структуре  простого предложения,  которое можно понимать как единицу языка и единицу речи (высказывание). Эти подходы тесно связаны  между собой и как бы составляют единое целое, не стоит их противопоставлять друг другу.

Comment: В чем там разница? Единица языка – это синтаксическое определение вида предложения, а единица речи – это применение обозначенной структуры к конкретной ситуации. В приведенных вами примерах синтаксис одинаковый, но конкретика разная, в том числе может быть изменен порядок слов в зависимости от контекста.

Comment: Единица речи я думаю это как раз синтаксические понятия типа обстоятельства/дополнения/ определения. А единица языка это существительное глагол и тд. Налицо, так сказать, конфликт одних единиц с другими. Например, если я говорю "на стуле", то я говорю "на чем", а меня пытаются уверить, что я говорю "где". Аналогично со сказуемым.

Answer (score 1):

**Ответ на комментарий**

Цитата: *"**Единица речи,** я думаю, это как раз синтаксические понятия типа обстоятельства/дополнения/ определения. А **единица языка** это существительное глагол и т.д.".*

Так существует ли вообще в современном языкознании этот термин –  **предложение как единица языка**? Ответ на этот вопрос дан отдельной темой.

**Предложение как единица языка и как единица речи**

1. **История** изучения простого предложения интересна сама по себе. Предложение – одна из основных грамматических категорий синтаксиса. В России первые теоретические труды появились  в конце XIX – начале XX века, но общепризнанного понимания до сих пор нет.
2. Сначала внимание было сосредоточено на **формальном** устройстве предложения, а сам термин использовался и по отношению к предложению, и по отношению к логическому суждению. **Логическое направление** (по Ф.И. Буслаеву)  в понимании предложения было тогда основным.

Четко просматривалась **связь мышления и языка**:  мысль должна быть оформленной в виде предложения. Подлежащее – это предмет, о котором мы судим, а сказуемое – то, то мы думаем о нем. Без сказуемого не может быть суждения,  это главный член предложения. Безличные предложения допускались, но назывные – нет. Признавалось существование  именного сказуемого при наличии  связки,  в то же время многие считали, что сказуемым должен быть только глагол.

3. Но уже внутри логической школы стали намечаться **разногласия** – не всегда логика точно совпадала с такой грамматикой.  В конце 19 века обозначилось  **психологическое** направление   (А.А. Потебня).  Логика только регистрировала результат мышления, но не сам процесс. Предложение должное соединять два понятия (субъект и предикат) – **не так важно**, что назвать подлежащим, а что сказуемым.
4. Но и такое понимание предложения уже  не казалось удовлетворительным. Была высказана идея о том, что синтаксис надо вовсе **отделить от процесса мышления,** сделать его самостоятельным. А В 60-е годы XX века  началась «осада, а потом штурм»  семантики – появилось **семантическое** направление, а также новая терминология: предложение **как единица языка** и предложение **как единица речи.**
5. **Имеет ли знаковую природу само предложение**, можно ли его считать единицей языка, не разделяя на части. Стали изучаться структурные схемы простых предложения. Это очень важный момент:  теперь считалось, что предложение **не создается нами в процессе речи, а только воспроизводится по уже существующим структурно-грамматическим моделям.** Отсюда следует, что нужно изучать эти структуры, а потом уже применять к  реальности.  В нашем сознании уже существуют определенные языковые модели, носители языка  пользуются  ими интуитивно.
6. Итак, предложение как **явление языка** соответствует грамматике, а предложение как **высказывание** имеет  целевое назначение  и применяется к конкретной ситуации.  Вот об этом нужно всегда помнить при  синтаксическом анализе предложений – **что говорим, кому говорим и зачем говорим.** И конечно, понимать,  какую грамматику (структурную модель)  мы собираемся использовать.

Материал взят из книги В.И. Казариной «Простое предложение в аспекте структурно-семантического подхода», Москва, 2019 г.

Comment: Я вижу, что информация осталась НЕВОСТРЕБОВАННОЙ и никого не заинтересовала (уже привычный для меня  стандарт: ни одного голоса, ни одного комментария, ни одного вопроса). Да только зря, ведь это ОСНОВА ОСНОВ для современного анализа грамматики простого предложения.  А еще это очень долгий путь поисков, пройденный  удивительными и преданными  науке людьми.

Answer (score 0):

Замените знаки вопроса на основе материала ниже

```
"Печатать было интереснее, чем читать" (сказуемое: ??)

"Было интереснее печатать, чем читать" (сказуемое: ??)
```

http://philolog.pspu.ru/module/magazine/do/mpub_15_303

> Трудность может возникнуть, когда инфинитив сочетается со словами на
> –О(-Е): если инфинитив стоит на первом месте в предложении, а дальше
> следует слово на –О, перед нами двусоставное предложение с подлежащим - инфинитивом: Спорить с ним бесполезно. Шутить с либерализмом опасно. Перестановка инфинитива на второе место после слова на –О, являющегося
> категорией состояния, превращает предложение в безличное: Бесполезно
> спорить с ним. Непросто было добраться до работы в этот день из-за
> метели. Опасно шутить с либерализмом. Наличие при инфинитиве слов
> категории состояния надо, нужно, необходимо, нельзя, можно и др.
> говорит о том, что это сказуемое безличных предложений, независимо от
> порядка слов: У вас тут можно заблудиться. Спрашивать об этом было
> нельзя. Надо найти другое решение.
> )

Comment: Спасибо! Значит, в моем предложении подлежащее "печатать", а сказуемое "интереснее".